# Trying to remove public from url Laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it didn't work as you can see in the screenshot below:

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cox4x.png

However if I change my .htaccess file to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Then I can see this on my browser:

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8eMv.png

This is how my folder structure looks like:

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDZA0.png

**What have I tried?**

I have already enabled my `mod_rewrite` in XAMPP to try to fix my solution. I had followed these steps in the link below:

Link: http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which editor is this? https://i.imgur.com/t91w2OH.png

Comment: Sublime text 3 with Seti UI theme.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought it was [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is point the home directory of your site config in Apache to the `public` folder of your Laravel installation.
Currently, it seems to point to its root folder.

Comment: Any other solution is just crap

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean. You mean like this in my hosts file?: 127.0.0.1     localhost/portfolio-zaky-2/public/    But that didn't worked for me.

Comment: Nope, not in your host file. In your Apache config for your local dev website.

Answer (score 0):

In your vhost you should make the domains documentroot point to the /public folder.

DocumentRoot "/home/vhostsfolder/laravelproject/public"

instead of

DocumentRoot "/home/vhostsfolder/laravelproject"

What server are you using? Local/sharedhosting/vps ?